# Robolectric - GreenDao callbacks not being called

Tags: android, robolectric, greendao

We are using Robolectric and want to run operations on our GreenDao database. We are using AsyncSession and IAsyncOperationCompletedListener, and waiting for the 
onOperationCompleted() callback to be called. However, it seems like with Robolectric, this is never being called. This is verified both by just debugging breakpoints and but setting a CountDownLatch which just times out.

Is there a way to make this work?

```
int sequenceId = mAsyncSession.insertOrReplaceInTx(Object.class, objects).getSequenceNumber();


public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
   // This is never reached
}
```